# Slow internet, high ping/jitter on Ethernet on Windows 10 only

Tags: windows-10, networking, lan, wired-networking

My desktop PC (Windows 10) has slow internet, high ping and jitter on Ethernet.

I ran out of ideas on how to troubleshoot and fix this.

**[UPDATE]** This happens on this **Windows 10 only** (ie. software issue). It's fine on Linux on the same machine, and on other Windows 10 laptops.

**[UPDATE 2]** I get slow speed on [speedtest.net](https://speedtest.net) and [speedtest.exetel.com.au](https://speedtest.exetel.com.au/) (my Internet provider's) only, on all browsers (Chrome, IE 11, Firefox, Edge, Brave). But I just tested Torrent and got full speed! Now I am really confused.

**[UPDATE 3]** I noticed a download (from the same Chrome browser) could reach fullspeed! Immediately re-tested speedtest and get half-speed as usual. This is too weird.

**The issue:**

Average result using the same LAN cable / docking station:

- On the desktop (Windows 10):
  **20** Mbps / 18 Mbps, 30ms / 10ms (<--  Download/Upload, Ping/Jitter)
- On the same desktop (Ubuntu) and on other Windows 10 laptops:     
  **52** Mbps / 18 Mbps, 13ms / 2ms

**My findings so far:**

- It is **not** the router or LAN cable, because the same cable achieves much higher speed and much lower ping/jitter on my other Windows 10 laptops (both directly (Ethernet port) or via docking station (USB 3), WiFi disabled to be sure).
- It is **not** my [docking station](https://plugable.com/products/ud-3900), because using Ethernet from the docking station on laptop (via the same USB 3 cable) is still fast, and plugging in the LAN cable directly on the PC is still slow.
- *[UPDATE]* It is **not** the hardware, because when I try Ubuntu USB on the same machine it is fast (same speed as my laptops).

**What I have tried:**

- Made sure no other programs is using the Internet when running speed test.
  [image]
- Made sure no bottleneck on CPU/memory/disk
- https://www.pcerror-fix.com/windows-10-slow-internet-fixed
- The Optimal setting of [TCP Optimizer](https://www.speedguide.net/downloads.php)
- Updated most drivers using [Snappy Driver Installer](https://www.snappy-driver-installer.org/) (will update the rest as they're over 4GB each!)

Comment: How is the docking station connected to the laptop.  What are the specifications of the USB LAN adapter?  Instead of submitting a comment you should edit your question

Comment: By unplugging the USB 3 cable from the PC and plugging it in to the laptop - Is that what you mean? I'm not sure how to check the specs of the USB LAN adapter. I have edited my question. Thanks

Comment: What's the usual CPU usage on the PC? What's the _CPU_ on the PC? (Perhaps it literally can't keep up?) What non-USB Ethernet card does the PC have? Have you tested using other tools than web-based Speedtest (e.g. iperf3)?

Comment: CPU usage is pretty low (25% when running speedtest, 3% otherwise).
Both the ethernet port and the USB 3 port on the PC are part of the motherboard. It used to be fast, I don't know how long it's been slow, I only noticed after I started using a docking station. I can't think of any other changes that have happened.
I'm not sure how to use iperf3, could you please suggest the command?

Comment: You don’t have the part number of the USB LAN adapter?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not using a USB LAN adapter. The LAN cable can be plugged into the dock, which has USB connection to the PC/laptop.

Comment: Yes; Yes you are using a USB LAN adapter since your docking station is connected by USB 3.0; Know I understand the specifications of the USB LAN adapter; What are the specifications for the desktops adapter

Comment: @Ramhound How can I find out?

Comment: Did you try to update driver of all components where internet passthrough ?

Comment: @Elikill58 Good point! I thought I did but I haven't updated all yet! I will try updating all thanks!

Comment: I would build an WinRE USB stick or a fresh Windows 10 parallel install and test if the problem still occurs. May be you have "optimized" long time ago something in Windows that now causes problems.

Comment: I personally don't believe in driver installers. What are your network adapter on the desktop and its driver version? Have you tried an external network adapter?

Comment: @Robert I believe it won't occur on a fresh Windows 10 (because I tested on other Windows 10 laptops, and tested on Linux on the same machine).

Comment: @harrymc I tried connecting it via a docking station but it's still the same. Drivers: Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller 10.50.511.2021 (11 May 2021) and Plugable Ethernet 10.1.2664.0 (22 Feb 2021)

Comment: There is a newer [Realtek driver](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software) and a newer [Plugable Ethernet](https://plugable.com/pages/wired-ethernet-network-adapters-drivers/). Better verify that my links truly relate to your devices.

Comment: If Windows and Ubuntu use the same IP, the router can be ruled out _(if they don't, configure them with the same IP to test)_, else it's either the adapter's drivers _(pull the drivers directly from the network adapter's OEM's site)_ or the driver settings: `ncpa.cpl` → Right-click adapter → _Properties_ → _Configure..._ → _Advanced_

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks, I can rule out router. Pretty certain on drivers too. Now my network adapter properties: MAC address not present, Priority & VLAN enabled, Speed & Duplex auto (I tried all), VLAN ID 0, Wake enabled

Comment: Why do you rule out drivers?

Comment: That snappy driver installer might actually be the source of the problem. RealTek NICs can be flaky. The newest driver is not always the best. I usually start at the newest driver and work backwards until I find a stable version.

Comment: Working for an ISP we see this a lot... It is often anti-virus, security, internet protection, anti-malware, or other software designed to protect your system. Try disabling/exiting everything running in the system tray.

Comment: See if these instructions work. https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/1720415

Comment: @harrymc Thx for the links, I have tried the Realtek one, but not the Plugable one (I've got UD-3900, which uses DisplayLink driver), so I've tried 2 different hardware connections and 5 drivers, all same result.

Comment: @acejavelin Firewall and all other running programs was one of the first things I tried, thanks anyway for the good suggestion.

Comment: @desbest Immediately after Method 3 (`ipconfig /...`) I see a slight increase in download speed (from 20 to 23 Mbps), but it doesn't last long

Comment: The cause is most likely faulty or outdated drivers. If not, then installing drivers using an `.exe` file that is NOT running as administrator.

Comment: My suggestion if you're installing drivers, that you should not open the `.exe` `.cab` `.msi` `.msu` file to install it, and instead install it using Device Manager by having Device Manager then point to that to the appropriate folder. https://www.thewindowsclub.com/uninstall-disable-roll-back-update-drivers-windows

Comment: Did you try to install a virtual machine with virtualbox under Linux (as host) with a fresh install of windows 10 as guest?  If you will obtain max speed under the guest windows 10, then you will be sure that is in some additional driver/software/antivirus/antimalware installed (so not in the OS components themselves). Then you can proceed installing them and checking when the speed falls down.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into consideration all the details in your question and all the comments below it, I'd look for a solution elsewhere. Namely, in the software.

OS level network tuning is one thing and software has its ways to influence connections. This would explain why your torrents are fine.

I won't give you exact steps here. Just a few points:

- What browsers have you tried? Can you give a go to some other ones and compare?
- Search the web for "browser flags". These are runtime parameters, which may help.
- If you're into software compilation, you might take a look, what can be done there. (Just an idea, I'm not sure, what you'll find.)
- Analyse the traffic with Wireshark. This will give you more info, but it's a slightly advanced topic.

**Edit:** It still doesn't explain ping and jitter, but can introduce some news.

**Edit:** Malicious software activity also crossed my mind.